# Change regex to not allow string v2?

Tags: .net, regex, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a current url redirection, I need to change this so that It doesn't match if it has `v2` in the url.

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 65">
    <match url="^mobile/(.+)/jobs/(.[^\.]+)/$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="mobile/templates/MobileJobDetailView.aspx?area={R:1}&amp;jobtag={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>
```

This should match this url:

http://www.website.local/jobs/test.aspx

But not this one:

http://m.website.local/mobile/v2/jobs/test/

I tried changing the regex to this:

`^mobile/(.+)(?!.*v2)/jobs/(.[^\.]+)/$`

But that's abouts as far as I've gotten, I'd love some help here!

Answer (score 0):

use this regex pattern

**String pat="((.+)website.*test\?(\.aspx)?)"**

*Explanation:*

(.+)= looks for one or more characters before website eg http://www.mobile

.* = looks for zero or more characters after website and before test

(\.aspx)? = checks to see if there is .aspx in the line , ? makes it optional

Hope this helps